# Какой URL у ServerSocket'a?

Tags: java, ajax

Какой `URL` у `ServerSocket`'a? Я поднимаю вебсокет с портом под номером 4444, и хочу послать ему данные посредством ajax запроса из своего веб-приложения, для этого необходим `URL`. Является ли `127.0.0.1:4444` допустимым значением `URL` в этом случае?

Answer (score 1):

Веб-сокет (как и любой другой сетевой сокет) должен состоять как минимум из ip-адреса и порта.

Порт у вас есть, осталось определить хост (IP). Используйте домен, на котором расположен сайт (или, например, localhost, если разрабатываете сайт локально на своей машине).

Пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090530/how-to-point-a-websocket-to-the-current-server

P.S. Не путайте пожалуйста AJAX и WebSocket. Ajax - это односторонние запросы `клиент->сервер`. Сокеты - это двусторонний обмен `клиент<->сервер`.